# How to build a BlackBerry Native Live TV App for BB 10 using BlackBerry Native SDK

Tags: c++, c, blackberry-10

How to build a  native Live TV application using BlackBerry Native SDK . I have already tried rss news and Video playback examples

as mentioned in the sample.

I have   xml.aspx kind of  url which contains my channel images, names and url's etc

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: How to parse  the url i.e  xml.aspx  file conatining my channel images, url's and channel names  and show  in the native App.   I have tried and bult sample  applications rss news and videoplayback etc already.

Comment: Please refer to the  link for details on tools etc and the BlackBerry native platform /coding    http://developer.blackberry.com/native/

Comment: My main target is to   parse my  url containing images, url's and  channel names  for my Live TV Application in   .cpp or .c  i.e C++ or C language